# Detect Code Completion event in IntelliJ

Tags: intellij-idea, intellij-plugin

I'm trying to find the way to detect if a Code Completion event occurred. My task is to find out the Name of the Class that has been typed up or maybe find them when save is pressed.

How can I make my plugin run on an event happening in the IntelliJ IDE?

Comment: Please explain what you need in more detail. Items in the code completion list can be anything, not necessarily classes. Also I don't quite understand what save has to do with code completion.

Comment: Save was when I was trying to decide on an event. But that kind of irrelevant now. 

What I am trying to do is, during Android development many Api Classes are used that use some kind of permissions. I want to make a plugin that can suggest possible permissions, show those options in a popup like the on for Spell check and then add that permission to the AndroidManifest file.

Comment: @yole I forgot to tag you.

Comment: You need to write an intention action. You can see a video showing the development of an intention action here: http://blog.jetbrains.com/idea/2012/12/webinar-recording-live-coding-a-plugin-from-scratch/